# What's the equivalent parameter for Instagram MIN_LIKE_ID

Tags: api, instagram

I need to iterate through particular user's likes using API below

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/liked
```

How can I skip what i have read before? there is a "max_like_id" parameter, but i need to get "the newest likes" just after some particular id.
Already tried "min_like_id", but still all likes are returned.

Comment: No, if its not in doc, it does not exist

Comment: I know that, i mean is there any workaround? anybody know something?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `min_like_id` for this endpoint.

You can do this manually:

1. save the `media_id` of the first photo that is loaded on from the API
2. create a function to load only newest, this should get API response and iterate thru the media objects and compare with the saved `media_id` in step 1
3. if there is no match, prepend the media to the list, if there is match then break out of the loop, and update the variable that saved the `media_id` in step 1 to the first `media_id` in step 2

Comment: Hmm, i like the idea of breaking the loop if found previously saved id. Right now i'm implementing "local" save also, but still have to iterate throughout all likes count just to get the "new likes". I will try to implement this, thanks